# read permission issue for htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have successfully installed the LAMP stack to support phpipam application
Also, I have a test file in:
    /var/www/html/test.php
and can load it via:
    http://127.0.0.1/index.php
However, when I try to access:
    http://127.0.0.1/phpipam
I get the following error in the httpd error log:
    (13)Permission denied: /var/www/html/phpipam/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable
I verified that I set the configurations correctly in the file
    /var/www/html/phpipam/.htaccess

I also set the directory's file permissions to
    777
but I'm still not able to access the site.

Any idea where I might have gone wrong?

Comment: check the __file__'s permission bits. Setting directory's permission to 777 can still allow for an unreadable `.htaccess` file for the Apache user.

Comment: thanks, hjpotter92, that was the issue. I thought I changed the directory/file permissions using "-R " but did not and so .htaccess file didn't have the correct permission bit set.

Comment: np. You can self-answer this question, and mark it as selected. :)